# Android kernel dynamic NAND partition layout?

Tags: android, memory, kernel

I'm making some changes to the 2.6.35 Android kernel to support a chinese device, what has three flavors: 128MB NAND, 256MB NAND and 2GB NAND. In this device, the kernel handles MTD layout (instead of bootloader). And such, I would like to make it possible to have extended/different layouts on bigger NANDs. Basically, a 128MB setup, with extensions to support higher NAND amount. The current one simply uses a remaining space switch, and thus I only get a huge MTD partition. But I want more smaller partitions (to be more AOSP).

So, my new layout would be:

- 128MB NAND:

  - 512kB bootloader
  - 8MB kernel
  - (128MB minus following) rootfs
- 256MB NAND:

  - 128MB NAND layout, except that rootfs is 128MB
  - remaining as cache
- 2GB NAND:

  - 256MB NAND layout, except that cache is 128MB
  - Remaining as userdata

Would this be possible, as it would need dynamic handling of the NAND size? As I don't want to compile 3 different kernels for one device with different specs...